# Writing to standard output

Tags: windows, delphi, windows-10, stdout

I'm following the official [Language Overview](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Language_Overview#Example_Programs).

This is the program (verbatim from the guide, saved as `greeting.dpr`):

```
 program Greeting;

 {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

 var
   MyMessage: string;

 begin
   MyMessage := 'Hello world!';
   Writeln(MyMessage);
 end.
```

It compiles fine via `dcc32 greeting` and produces an executable `greeting.exe`:

```
Embarcadero Delphi for Win32 compiler version 33.0
Copyright (c) 1983,2018 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
greeting.dpr(12)
13 lines, 0.03 seconds, 35480 bytes code, 15812 bytes data.
```

But when I run the executable from the command line, it just ends without writing anything to standard output:

```
C:\Users\xehpuk\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\Greeting>greeting.exe

C:\Users\xehpuk\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\Greeting>greeting

C:\Users\xehpuk\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\Greeting>
```

Excerpt from the content of the executable:

[image: Content of the executable]

Why?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: When you write "I run the executable from the command line", I assume you type "greeting" in a CMD prompt?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes. Edited it into the post.

Comment: Well, something is wrong, but it is not the source code in the snippet above. Some things to try: (0) Make sure you are running the right file (look at its date, path). (1) Make sure the DPR file is in ASCII. (2) Open the compiled EXE in a hex editor to verify that it is the right file: you should be able to read `H e l l o   w o r l d !` in it (with nulls between the chars). (3) Try to run it on a different machine (antivirus?) (4) Try to run "greeting > file.txt" or "greeting | clip" to see if there is something wrong with your console window (exceedingly unlikely). (5) Run `where dcc32` to

Comment: Does it work if you compile and run from IDE (F9)? (But add `Readln;` at the end to stop and stare until Enter key)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I've tried anything but (3). Output for (5): `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin\DCC32.EXE`

Comment: Then (3) is very interesting. Do you have any antivirus or antimalware software that might prevent the application from running?

Comment: Got the solution: adding `uses System.SysUtils;` helps. Not sure why though.

Comment: And if you remove `uses System.SysUtils;` again, it reverts back to printing nothing?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes.

Comment: Strange. I'd love to get a technical explanation for this. On my system, it works just fine without that unit, although in any real app, that unit would be the first thing you'd include.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Importing anything from `System` helps, e.g. `System.TimeSpan`.

Comment: @xehpuk: Possibly because they import `SysUtils` (almost every unit includes that one).

Comment: What happens if you run the program in the debugger? Perhaps you get an exception? Exception handling is different with `SysUtils`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224931/discussion-between-xehpuk-and-andreas-rejbrand).